# Can I calculate the geometric mean with django annotation?

Tags: django, postgresql, geometric-mean

Is there a way to use it like

```
Foo.objects.annotate(geometric_mean=GeometricMean('bars__value'))
```

or

```
Foo.objects.annotate(geometric_mean=Power(Prod('bars__value'), Count('bars'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something quite similar: you can calculate the average of the natural logarithms:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models.functions import Ln

Foo.objects.annotate(geometric_mean=Avg(Ln('bars__value')))
```

then the geometric mean is the exponent of this. If you really need the geometric mean itself, then you can use [**`Exp`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#exp) on that result:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models.functions import Exp, Ln

Foo.objects.annotate(geometric_mean=Exp(Avg(Ln('bars__value'))))
```

but you do not need this if you for example only want to *order* by two geometric means, since the exponent leaves the order relation intact: *e<sup>a</sup>≤e<sup>b</sup>* implies *a≤b* and vice versa.

This works because *ln(x<sub>1</sub>×x<sub>2</sub>×…×x<sub>n</sub>)* is equivalent to *ln(x<sub>1</sub>)+ln(x<sub>2</sub>)+…+ln(x<sub>n</sub>)*, and *ln(x<sup>y</sup>)* is equivalent to *y×ln(x)*.